# Overview - what skills are needed for sensor fusion?

Tags: sensors, sensor-fusion

I want to make a list of what knowledge is necessary for [sensor fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion). Since it has a wide array of possible applications, it is not clear where to begin studying. Can *we* please verify add topics that are in-scope, and specify to what extent?:

1. [Digital Signal Processing course](https://www.coursera.org/course/dsp)
2. [Probability Course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-spring-2006/lecture-notes/)
3. Machine Learning - course at Coursera from Stanford University
4. Programming robotic car - course at Udacity
5. Knowledge of Matlab and Simulink - tutorials on mathworks webpage and offline help.
6. Basic knowledge about integrals, matrices operations, differential equations.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics.SE! There's a lot of question all rolled up into one. You might consider splitting this into several questions. However, your main question is essentially a list question, which is discouraged on StackExchange in general, as there is no one right answer. Maybe our [FAQ](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq) can help you rephrase the question in a more answerable way.

Comment: Welcome *josh131* there's definitely an interesting question (or evenseveral  questions) buried in here, so feel free to either edit this question or start a new question (or questions). For an explanation of why we try to avoid *list* questions, see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/138432) on teh stack exchange meta site.

Comment: This question is basically no different than [This one](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/138/mathematical-prerequisites-for-beginning-graduate-student-in-robotics), except that it is less-well-posed. I think the problem here is the lack of a solid definition about "sensor fusion." I'll edit it then we can revisit closing. For now I think it's valid.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but it could be helpful to future viewers if you add the links for "Machine Learning" and below.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip all but 2,6,5, if you want to learn how sensor information is fused to form a consistent estimate of something. 5 is optional but helpful. The best course you can take is a Optimal Estimation / Filtering course, and a Probabilities and Stochastic Processes course. Try MIT Courseware for both of those.

Comment: I have been dabbling with those courses. There are many of them and I'm not sure which would be the best to follow on MIT courseware. I have not found exactly with the name you specified, Optimale Estimation/Filtering. Which one exactly do you recommend?

Comment: This is exactly Optimal Estimation / Filtering. Review the requirements for this course, make sure you satisfy them, then take this course. It's your best bet.